# How can spacy classify text as belonging to one of several labels

Tags: python, text, nlp, classification, spacy

How can I classify projects into one of several categories based on their titles and/or descriptions. I have a list of several projects with titles and descriptions, and each one can be classed as one of several categories depending on the keywords within those categories. So for example, in the first image, the first project would be classed as healthcare and the second project would be classed as materials, based on the keywords in the second image.

[image]

[image]

I've been searchng for some tutorials, but they mostly seem to show how to categorise text as being either positive or negative, which isn't what I need. Any pointers to tutorials would also help

Comment: The most brute force (and simple) approach would be to just check whether the keywords from image two can be found in each cell of image one.

Comment: I did that manually, without using spacy - just using regex and searching each project title and description cell for each keyword. But I thought there has to be a more effective way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, "positive" and "negative" are just labels, and they don't get special treatment, so you should be able to use those tutorials as guides anyway. You might find an example project about text categorization, like [this one](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/textcat_docs_issues), helpful.

Basically you have to create training data and a training config and train a model, same as any spaCy model. The sample project has an example of all of that except creating the initial training data - it uses pre-existing data and just converts it.